# Why is this repeating if you put in the correct answer?

Tags: python, loops

Why is this repeating please HELP! When you run this the code keeps on running again after you put in the correct answer pls help

```
player1pokemonchoice = 'empty'
while player1pokemonchoice != '1' and player1pokemonchoice != '2' and 
player1pokemonchoice != '3' and player1pokemonchoice != '4':
    number = input('''
********PLAYER 1 POKEMON CHOICE********
1. Bulbasaur
HP: between 500 - 1000
ATTACKS:

2. Charmander
HP: between 100 - 500
ATTACKS:

3. Squirtle
HP: between 250 - 750
ATTACKS:

4. Pikachu
HP: between 100 - 600
ATTACKS:
''')
    if player1pokemonchoice == '1':
        print ('TEST')
    elif player1pokemonchoice == '2':
        print ('TEST')
    elif player1pokemonchoice == '3':
        print ('TEST')
    elif player1pokemonchoice == '4':
        print ('TEST')
```

Comment: Because you never update `player1pokemonchoice`. You instead update a variable called `number` that you then never use.

Comment: Your code would be much easier to read if you tested: while player1pokemonchoice not in ('1', '2', '3', '4'):  You could even convert to an integer and test while 0 < choice < 5: and you could replace the if ... elif ... chain with a "dispatch" table ... a dictionary {1: 'result1', 2: 'result2' ...} and simply lookup the results/response (which could actually be a function) in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Check your variables - "number" and "player1pokemonchoice".
"number" is not being assigned "player1pokemonchoice".

Comment: It has been assigned before

Comment: Assigned before doesn't matter :-) since you need it in the while loop. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some things to think about.

If you're going to write a game entailing a table of creatures (such as Pokémon) with a bunch of attributes (name, range of hit points, etc) then you probably want to structure you code around these data structures.  Let the data provide the details for objects your using.

Here's some simple restructuring of your code as a crude example:

```
#!python
# would normally be: #!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict

if hasattr(__builtins__, 'raw_input'):
    input = raw_input

menu_header = '''
********PLAYER 1 POKEMON CHOICE********
'''

menu_item = '''
{p.choice} {p.name}
HP: between {p.low} - {p.high}
ATTACKS:
'''

pokemon = namedtuple('pokemon', ['choice', 'name', 'low', 'high', 'results'])

stats = (
  (1, 'Bulbasaur',  500, 1000, 'results for %s'),
  (2, 'Charmander', 100,  500, 'different results for %s'),
  (3, 'Squirtle',   250,  750, "%s's results"),
  (4, 'Pikachu',    100,  600, 'and so on for %s'),
  )

army = OrderedDict()

for each in stats:
    army[each[0]] = pokemon(*each)

menu = menu_header + ''.join([menu_item.format(p=x) for x in army.values()])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    choice = -1
    while choice not in (1,2,3,4):
        choice = raw_input(menu)
        try:
            choice = int(choice)
        except ValueError as e:
            print('Unable to parse choice as an integer: %s' % choice)
            print('Please Try again:')
            continue
        print(army[choice].results % army[choice].name)
```

In this example I'm doing a lot of things which you'll want to learn if you're going to master Python.  For one thing I have a "shebang" line which is used on Unix, Linux, MacOS X and other Unix like systems to associate a script file with the interpreter which can execute it.  The first #! line is there for StackOverflow's rendering engine.  It sees that and adds color syntax highlighting to my code.  The next comment line shows a more typical "shebang" as you'd find it on most systems.

(Python users generally use the `env` utility from the Posix specification to find whichever Python interpreter is on the user's PATH.  This allows users to configure their accounts and shell sessions to select their preferred version and installation of Python ... which is useful for maintaining all their dependencies and customizations to the language's environment).

The line about `from __future__ import` ... is there to handle Python2 while transitioning towards Python version 3 or later (the future).  In older versions of Python `print` was a reserved keyword, used in statements.  In modern versions of Python `print()` is a function which can be used in expressions (and which can be over-ridden).

We'll talk about these classes I've imported from [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) momentarily.

The next couple of lines also provides backwards compatibility between Python2 and modern versions of the language.  This is somewhat more obscure because real-world programs rarely used the `input()` or `raw_input()` (Most input in modern programming is read from GUI dialog functions, from files or sockets, from special "request" objects supplied by web servers, or via other APIs -- applications programming interfaces).

But these to lines basically allow you to call `input()` as you probably intended.  The old `input()` function was actually a way to read input ***and parse it with the interpreter***.  It was almost always better to use `raw_input()` and separately perform sanity checks on the data before, possibly, passing it for interpreter evaluation.  (In fact it's almost always a bad idea to pass user input to your programming interpreter for evaluation ... but Python's old semantics were a legacy of its very early intended focus for teaching elementary programming).  In newer versions of Python `input()` acts like the old `raw_input()` and the way to emulate the old semantics would be to call `eval(input())` if you were intent on doing that).

Now the **namedtuple** and **OrderedDict** functionality which I've imported is going to provide us with ways structure our program around a table describing our different types of Pokémon.

A tuple, is a simple, immutable data structure.  Outside of Python the term is most often used to refer to the "rows" in a database (or as returned by an SQL query).  But Python tuples can be a bit tedious to work with because you'd have to access the individual fields ("columns" in a database table) using index (numeric offsets from the beginning of each).

A **namedtuple** allows one to define a sort of lightweight object which behaves like a tuple (and has the performance and memory consumption advantages of tuples) but which also allows us to access the fields by their names.

As with many object oriented programming and scripting languages, normal Python objects have "attributes" (like fields) which are accessed using the "dot" operator.  So the "height" attribute of a "Rectangle" object could be accessed as myRectangle.height.

This is precisely how we can access the attributed of of `pokemon` namedtuples.  When I instantiate each of them I must supply all of the values for each field: choice, name, low and high HP limits, and so on.  (The fact that I pass the name of my resulting namedtuple "class" as the first argument to the `namedtuple()` factory function is a quirk that has to do with how the objects of this type will be represented in the interpreter, during debugging, etc).

If you read through the rest of the code you'll see where I have a table of "stats."  That's a tuple of tuples.  This is a reasonably compact to supply a small table full of data.  But it also maps well to some hypothetical future version of our program where we're storing ten thousand types of Pokémon in a database and having our game load them up as part of its initialization (or even just loading just those which are part of a given session ... dynamically fetching them as they show up).

Then I create my Pokémon army as a "dictionary" (so I can easily look up any member by his menu choice number).  But I made this an "OrderedDict" --- a type of dictionary which maintains its entries in the same order in which they were added.  Usually we don't need to keep dictionaries in specific order; these data structures are normally maintained in some internal arrangement which is optimized for quick access by the dictionary's "key."  (We're using menu choice as the key; a more common arrangement might use the name as the key).

I populate my army in just two lines of code.  It wouldn't matter if you added 10,000 more entries to your "stats" table ... you could populate the whole army with just those same two lines.

That's what I mean by talking about structuring your code dynamically around your data tables.

One tricky part of those two lines: each of my `pokemon()` lightweight objects need to be called with five arguments.  But I'm iterating over whole entries from my hard-coded list (tuple) of stats.  The * in the line: `army[each[0]] = pokemon(*each)` is a special syntactic form in Python which "applies" the function across some variable containing a sequence of values (similar features exist in Ruby and JavaScript).

Basically this means that `pokemon(*each)` is evaluated as if I'd called `pokemon(each[0], each[1], each[2], ...)` (which, for a namedtuple is as if I'd called it with `pokemon(each.choice, each.name, each.low, ...)`).

I could have written that using "tuple unpacking" (which is a form of "destructuring"):

```
for ch, nm, lo, hi, res in stats:
    army[ch] = pokemon(ch, nm, lo, hi, res)
```

... this would accomplish the same thing.  But it's more verbose.  That would only make sense if I needed to add or remove some "columns" of data or do other things with these fields (columns) before instantiating each member of my army.

Once I have my army then I simply build the menu from it.  I take the menu_header and add a big string created by joining together menu_items.  Each menu_item is created by "rendering" (filling in) a little template using the string [.format()](https://pyformat.info/) method.

There are many other ways to do this sort of thing in Python.  There are a number of very complex and intricate template rendering engines in Python which are used extensively ... especially in web application development.

But this example just creates a fairly simple template (`menu_item`) which refers to the fields we're interested in from our `pokemon` object.  Note that I can use as many or as few of these fields/attributes as I like, in any order I like and repeately if I like. `p.choice` and `p.name` act as the names of "macros" for the template.  For more complex cases I could pass multiple objects to the method for example: `.format(p=this, m=something, o=other)`.

After all that set up then my "program" is only 9 lines long.  In this example I'm showing the conventional separator between your reusable module code (definitions of functions, initialization of hard-coded data structures, etc) from the code which should run run when this file is executed as a program.  (This allows the same file to be used as a module ... with an `import` statement ... as well as a standalone program.

Notice that I don't have any `if ... elif ... elif ...` in this code.  We don't need them.  I these behavior (in this case just the static "results" string templates) are embedded in our data table. Thus each `pokemon` object contains the necessary data for us to handle that selection.

In a real game it's likely we'd define a `class Pokemon(object):` ... and define methods (functions which are attributes of, "bound to") the class) and in our menu (or "event loop") we might do something more like:

```
while playing:
    choice = input(menu)
    if choice == 'q':
        playing = False
        continue
    monster = army[choice]
    results = monster.fight()
    print(results)
```

... or something like that.

The point of object oriented programming is that data (objects) can be created and composed to maintain their own state and supply their own behavior.  Thus the code wrapped around our objects only has to know how to access the behavior for the class as a whole rather than being coupled (tangled) with special handling for different instances.

In my "results" I'm using an even simpler and more primitive form of string template rendering (using the % operator on strings).  The "per" (percent) operator interpolates one or more value into a string to replace certain "printf" like patterns.  This is very roughly analogous to the numeric use of % as "module" because we can say that the string on the left of the operator is the result "modulo" (not including) the factors on the right).

Another feature of this code is the `try: ... except ValueError` ... I could have just made the `choice` fields strings and avoided this step.

But I wanted to also include an example of exception handling.

Input validation and exception/error handling is where most of the work of real programming lies.  Most programming is relatively straightforward, when you're give clean input on a perfectly operating system with a reliable network and so on.  But robust programs need to handle degenerate, even hostile, input under less-than-ideal conditions.

Comment: By the way, it was not at all clear what you'd want to do in your main (event) loop.  This program only loops until one valid choice is entered, then prints its "results" and drops out ... exits.  Obviously that's not what most games would do